# How to resize an Image with copy Command

Tags: image, yii2

Is it possible to resize an image using copy command?

Below is my code

```
copy((Yii::getAlias('@api/web/uploads/users/'.$model->id."_".$model->image)),
                            (Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/uploads/users/users_thumb/'.$model->id."_".$model->image)));
```

which copies an image from `users` folder inside `api` to `users_thumb` folder in `frontend`. Can i any how resize the image that is getting stored in the 
`user_thumb` folder?

Comment: You can use any thumbnail generate plugin / extension in yii2

Comment: I don't want to use any extension @PrakashPanchal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use [`copy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) to resize an image, but you could simply use [`yii2-imagine`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-imagine) extension, e.g. :

```
$src = Yii::getAlias("@api/web/uploads/users/{$model->id}_{$model->image}");
$dst = Yii::getAlias("@frontend/web/uploads/users/users_thumb/{$model->id}_{$model->image}";   
\yii\imagine\Image::thumbnail($src, 150, 150)->save($dst, ['quality' => 90]);
```

Or :

```
\yii\imagine\Image::getImagine()->open($src)
    ->thumbnail(new \Imagine\Image\Box(150, 150))
    ->save($dst, ['quality' => 90]);
```

Comment: i tried your first answer and it worked. thanks @soju